# how to loop through json data given below i m getting error

Tags: json, ajax

```
  "childtable_set": [
                    {
                        "season": 2014,
                        "goals": 43,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2015,
                        "goals": 26,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2016,
                        "goals": 37,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2017,
                        "goals": 34,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2018,
                        "goals": 34,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2014,
                        "goals": 43,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2015,
                        "goals": 26,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2016,
                        "goals": 37,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2017,
                        "goals": 34,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2018,
                        "goals": 34,
                        "fk": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "season": 2014,
                        "goals": 43,
                        "fk": 1
                    }
                ],
                "player_name": "Lionel Messi",
                "player_id": 1
            }
        ]



 $.ajax({
             url : final,
             dataType: "json",
             type: 'GET',
             success : function (data) {
                  // $("#resp").append("<p>"+(data.player_name)+"</p>")
                  // $("#resp").append("<p>"+data.childtable_set.player_id+"</p>")
                  // $("#resp").append("<p>"+data+"</p>")
                  for(var i = 0; i < data.childtable_set.length; i++){
                    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data.childtable_set[i].goals+"</p>")
                    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data[i].season+"</p>")
                    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data[i].player_id+"</p>")
                  }
                    }
                 });
             });
```

Error :

```
TypeError: data[1] is undefined cant access any data pasted complete ajax call please check out and help
```

Comment: JSON itself is not valid. You can check if JSON is correct or not from : https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: it is valid just check on the link you provided

Comment: No its not valid.. in list you are adding key value pair kind of data.. Please check..

Comment: data[0].childtable_set[i].goals thats how i able to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

if `data` is the object you've shown us, then it's not an array. Player_name is accessed with `data.player_name`. the array that contains goals and stuff is in `data.childtable_set`

Change your code to this :

```
success : function (data) {
    $("#resp").append("<p>"+(data.player_name)+"</p>")
    // $("#resp").append("<p>"+data+"</p>")
    for(var i = 0; i < data.childtable_set.length; i++){
    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data.childtable_set[i].goals+"</p>")
    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data.childtable_set[i].season+"</p>")
    $("#resp").append("<p>"+data.childtable_set[i].player_id+"</p>")
}
```

Comment: TypeError: data.childtable_set is undefined